handle scalar value in flink sql
I’m using Flink SQL to read data from multiple topics and join them together. In my calculations, I need to use a numeric value that might change over time. This value is fed from a specific topic, and I require that as soon as it changes, the new value should be used going forward. I tried to solve this issue by defining a versioned table in Flink and using a temporal join, but I encountered an error because I can’t define a join key.

Currently the join key in Temporal Table Join can not be empty.

I also attempted a cross join, but I received an error:

Table sink doesn’t support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by node Join.

here is my query:
SELECT order_id, subscription_id, (sub_total - saved_money) as price, saved_money, created_at from (
SELECT 
    o.id as order_id,
    vuo.order_tracking as subscription_id,
    o.sub_total as sub_total,
    least(vip.maximum_discount,o.delivery_fee) as saved_money,
    vuo.created_at as created_at
FROM 
    table1 vo
INNER JOIN 
    table2 AS vu ON vo.pro_subscription_id = vu.id
INNER JOIN 
    table3 AS vuo ON vu.vip_order_id = vuo.id
INNER JOIN 
    orders AS o ON vo.order_id = o.id
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT maximum_discount FROM updating_table WHERE id = 71) VIP
    );

I need maximum_discount from updating_table, it could be changed during the time.
note: I'm storing the result table in Kafka with insert into.
create table commands:
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
    order_id int,
    pro_subscription_id int
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = '',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '',
    'properties.group.id' = 'flink',
    'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',
    'value.avro-confluent.schema-registry.url' = '',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
    'properties.client.id' = 'flink',
    'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
    'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
    'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="" password="";');

Update:
I tested temporal join with these queries:
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    id INT,
    maximum_discount INT,
.....
    
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = '',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '',
    'properties.group.id' = 'flink',
    'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',
    'value.avro-confluent.schema-registry.url' = '',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
    'properties.client.id' = 'flink',
    'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
    'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
    'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="" password="";');

CREATE VIEW test2 AS     
    SELECT id,maximum_discount
FROM (
   SELECT id,maximum_discount,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
       ORDER BY updated_at DESC) AS rownum
   FROM test)
WHERE rownum = 1;

result table:
select o.id as order_id,test2.maximum_discount as discount
from orders o
join test2 FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF o.created_at on test2.id=71;


Can you share your CREATE TABLE commands?
I haven't read closely, but setting primary keys may help address the first issue.  The second error could be handled by having a sink table which accepts retract streams.

I updated the post. I can not set join key because I need just a value from updating_table and there is no relation between updating_table and other tables

Also define primary on table does not supported:
'avro-confluent' format doesn't support defining PRIMARY KEY constraint on the table, because it can't guarantee the semantic of primary key.

On which column or columns are trying to define the PRIMARY KEY constraint?  If it is over multiple fields, that could explain the error.  (The format cannot guarantee which over the columns are written and those could be routed to different partitions.)
Separately, have you looked at the upsert-kafka connector?  https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/upsert-kafka/

You should be able to define a PRIMARY KEY NOT ENFORCED constraint with the avro-confluent format.
